# Mock an IList.Add using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework-6, moq

I'm trying to setup a moq object to run some unit tests against the business layer object which uses EF6.
So far I can test simple methods invocations and check whether those methods were called. But, is there a way to test if an object was actually inserted into the underlying collection.

This is my mock method

```
private Mock<DbSet<T>> CreateMockDbSet<T>(IQueryable<T> entities) where T : class
{
    var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(entities.Provider);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(entities.Expression);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(entities.ElementType);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(entities.GetEnumerator());
    IList<T> list = entities as IList<T>;
    mockSet.As<IList<T>>().Setup(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<T>())).Returns(list.Add(It.IsAny<T>()));
    mockSet.Setup(m => m.Include(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(mockSet.Object);
    return mockSet;
}
```

I'm trying to mock the actual `Add` method from the list, but as written above is says there is no method `.Return`.

Is this even possible?

I need to validate if the object was inserted into my mock collection after some logic takes place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`IList.Add` method returns `void` so you cannot setup return, instead of it use `.Callback`

```
mockSet.As<IList<T>>()
    .Setup(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<T>()))
    .Callback<T>(item => list.Add(item));
```

or use `Capture.In`

```
mockSet.As<IList<T>>()
    .Setup(m => m.Add(Capture.In(list)));
```